# Font settings in chart series tooltip

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, mschart

Is it possible to change the font settings for tooltip text in the mschart control?

I've tried setting the chart series font, but it doesn't affect the tooltip associated with the series data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to change the font of the actual tooltip. If you view the page source what tag is the tooltip text sitting in?

You could probably manipulate it with something like QTip and JQuery to display a custom tooltip.